# Is there a way to make a game object pause whenever touching another game object? on c# from unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am trying to find a way to make a player move infinitely just by clicking the right arrow key ones and if it touches another game object it stops at the game objects postion and if button clicked again it moves again.

Note: I just started using unity also just started programming in c# so please try to explain things in an easy and understanding way.

Heres the code:

```
Rigidbody2D rb2d;
public float speed = 10;

public const string RIGHT = "right";
public const string LEFT = "left";
string buttonPressed;

public GameObject Rainbow_1;
public GameObject Rainbow_0;

bool isCol = false;

void Start() 
{ 
    rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>(); 
}
void Update() 
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)) { buttonPressed = RIGHT; }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) { buttonPressed = LEFT; }
    else { buttonPressed = null; } 
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if(buttonPressed == RIGHT)
    {
        if(isCol) 
        {
            StartCoroutine(sfos());
        }
        else if(!isCol)
        {
            rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(speed, 0);
        }                      
    }
}

IEnumerator sfos()
{
    Rainbow_0.transform.position = Rainbow_1.transform.position;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    Debug.Log("Collision detected");
    isCol = isCol;
}

private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D other) { isCol = !isCol; }
```

Comment: Depends on what your pause method is, also I'm a bit confused on what isCol = isCol; is

Comment: @Armin I'm inferring that as *is collided* based on `OnTriggerEnter2D`.

Comment: should be a typo @Armin, meaning isCol = !isCol

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is *stop* your player:

```
rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
```

You also need to signal a collision:

```
isCol = true;
```

---

###### Collision

You're not setting your `isCol` variable to `true` at any point outside of initialization. This means that your first collision will register, but all subsequent collisions will not; to fix this, change:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
    Debug.Log("Collision detected");
    isCol = isCol;
}
private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D other) { isCol = !isCol; }
```

To:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
    Debug.Log("Collision detected");
    isCol = true;
}
private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D other) { isCol = false; }
```

It's easier to see when it's explicit like this.

###### Velocity

For velocity, your `FixedUpdate` method is conditionally setting the velocity to `speed, 0`, but you never set it to anything else:

```
private void FixedUpdate() {
    if(buttonPressed == RIGHT) {
        if(isCol)  {
            StartCoroutine(sfos());
        }
        else if(!isCol) {
            rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(speed, 0);
        }                      
    }
}
```

You need to set your velocity to zero if you're not supposed to be moving; so if `isCol` is true:

```
private void FixedUpdate() {
    if(buttonPressed == RIGHT) {
        if(isCol)  {
            rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
            StartCoroutine(sfos());
        }
        else if(!isCol) {
            rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(speed, 0);
        }                      
    }
}
```

Additionally, for simplicity's sake, I *believe* Unity's 2D vector contains a property/field named `zero`, so the following may also work, but without direct access to Unity at the moment I won't promise anything.

```
rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero
```

Comment: take into account that with `StartCoroutine(sfos());` in a `FixedUpdate()` you are starting lots of coroutines, which is not a good idea :)

Comment: @rustyBucketBay I'll leave that to the OP as homework :)

Comment: unfortunately that did not solve the problem, but thank you though.